# "Update Lookups" prompt Box

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have this simple snippet of code to paste down a vlookup with a reference to an array in another workbook. However I keep getting that annoying prompt asking me to update the lookups..  I have made explicitly clear which file I want and its location, why is it asking me and how may I disable the prompt and make this automatic?

Many thanks,

```
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'\\Linkstation\rrm\Campaign Creator\Raw Data Generators\RDG\[power Event lookups.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R10000C2, 2, FALSE)"
Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826921

I beleive this is what you are looking for.

To suppress the message and to automatically update the links when you open a workbook in Excel 2002 or in Excel 2003, follow these steps:

```
1.On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the Edit tab. 
2.Click to clear the Ask to update automatic links check box.
```

To suppress the message and to automatically update the links when you open a workbook in Excel 2007, follow these steps:

```
1.Click Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
2.Click Advanced.
3.Under General, click to clear the Ask to update automatic links check box.
```